# Performance Impacts of Declaring a Variable With "let" Inside a Loop - Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm having trouble finding information on the performance impacts of declaring a variable with "let" inside of a loop in Javascript. I've found a lot of information about the scope of said variable if I do this, but not the performance impacts or lack thereof.

For example, in my code below (a binary search algorithm) I'm declaring the **midpoint** variable inside of my while loop.

```
const binarySearch = (arr, num) => {
  if(arr.length === 0) return false;
  if(arr.length === 1) return arr[0] === num;
  let left = 0;
  let right = arr.length - 1;
  while (left < arr.length && right >= 0){
    let midpoint = Math.floor((right + left) / 2);
    if(arr[midpoint] === num) return true;
    if(arr[midpoint] < num) left = midpoint + 1;
    else right = midpoint - 1;
  }
  return false;
}
```

My understanding is that this confines the scope of midpoint to the while loop itself, which I understand, and is just fine in this case.

I've found information saying that if I had used "var" to declare midpoint, instead of "let", the performance of declaring midpoint inside or outside of the loop wouldn't matter because "var" is automatically hoisted. Again, this makes sense, and I believe I understand it.

But I can't find information on if declaring midpoint with "let" inside the loop negatively impacts performance at all.

**Does this create a new variable in memory with each loop, therefore taking up more memory than if I first declared midpoint with "let" outside the loop and then simply updated its value with each loop?** See below for an example:

```
const binarySearch = (arr, num) => {
  if(arr.length === 0) return false;
  if(arr.length === 1) return arr[0] === num;
  let left = 0;
  let right = arr.length - 1;
  let midpoint;
  while (left < arr.length && right >= 0){
    midpoint = Math.floor((right + left) / 2);
    if(arr[midpoint] === num) return true;
    if(arr[midpoint] < num) left = midpoint + 1;
    else right = midpoint - 1;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: The compiler will optimize this so the same memory is used every time, don't worry about it.

Comment: `let` is about variable scope, not about how variables are stored.

Comment: First optimise for idiomatic code, not for performance. In fact, you shouldn't use `let` here, you should use `const midpoint`.